# Android ConstraintLayout sometimes doesn't draw correctly after switching between tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

I'm seeing a `ConstraintLayout` occasionally fail to draw correctly, but only when I switch between fragments, and I'm not seeing why.

It looks like this initially:
[image: It should look like this]

But, after switching tabs, it looks like this:
[image: Sometimes it looks like this]

***fragment_overview.xml*** (The `Fragment` layout)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/palette_grey_light"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <uk.lobsterdoodle.edinburghwolves.view.FixtureView
        android:id="@+id/overview_fixture_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    ... a few other views ...

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

***fixture_view.xml*** (The custom view layout, `FixtureView`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fixture_away_color"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/palette_red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fixture_home_color"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fixture_home_color"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/palette_grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fixture_away_color"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fixture_away_team_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="27"
        android:textColor="@color/palette_white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fixture_away_team_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fixture_away_team_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fixture_away_team_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:text="WOLVES"
        android:textColor="@color/palette_white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fixture_home_color"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fixture_away_team_score"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fixture_home_team_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="21"
        android:textColor="@color/palette_white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fixture_home_team_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fixture_home_team_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fixture_home_team_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:text="PIRATES"
        android:textColor="@color/palette_white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fixture_home_color"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fixture_home_team_score"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fixture_state"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="FINAL"
        android:textColor="@color/palette_white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fixture_away_team_score"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

While your `fixture_view.xml` file constrains views in the `ConstraintLayout` properly, a view in the `ConstraintLayout` in `fragment_overview.xml` isn't constrained, so they won't display properly at runtime. Add some some constraints to your `FixtureView` in `fragment_overview.xml` like so:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/palette_grey_light"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <!-- You were missing constraints here -->
    <uk.lobsterdoodle.edinburghwolves.view.FixtureView
        android:id="@+id/overview_fixture_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/palette_white"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:contentPadding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/overview_fixture_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="standings"
            android:textColor="@color/palette_grey"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Good point, thanks. However, I still get the same issue of the FixtureView collapsing on me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, by making the score `TextView`'s height `wrap_content` instead of matching constraint of `0dp`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fixture_away_team_score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <-- wrap, not 0dp
    ...
    />
```